# Science Fiction book where an experimental ship with a 2 navigator hyperspace system leaves the crew dead

Tags: story-identification, books, soft-sci-fi, hyperspace

Trying to find the title of a book I believe I read in the '70s. The plot involves around a hyperspace navigator that interfaces directly with the ship from a jump chair. Normal navigation was done with 1 navigator, but the ship he signs on with wants him to try an experimental system with 2 chairs and a 2nd navigator.

When he finally agrees they emerge from hyperspace to find the crew dead and they have traversed hyperspace in much less time then it should have taken.  They alter the ship's logs to hide what happened and are joined by the second navigator's mate (both alien). The aliens had previously been employed to keep an important shipment of seed alive during transport as they seem to be the only race that has been successful at doing so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first part of your question is pretty close to [*Star Rigger's Way*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?5382) (1978) by Jeffrey A. Carver.  The ship itself isn't experimental, though, it's the situation that is unprecedented.

Quoting the [Google books summary](https://books.google.ca/books?id=X15NBQAAQBAJ&dq=star%20rigger%27s%20way&source=gbs_navlinks_s):

> His shipmates dead, star rigger Gev Carlyle is adrift in the Flux, the subjective hyperspace that carries ships between the stars. His lone companion, and sole hope for survival, is a suicidal catlike alien named Cephean. Only a compatible rigger team, their visions meshed in psychic unity, can safely harness the turbulent currents of the Flux—and Carlyle's ship is sailing inexorably toward the deadly maelstrom of the Hurricane Flume. For even a chance at survival, he needs Cephean's help. But the price for that is a complete merging of minds and memories. And Carlyle, at war with his own past, dreads that union more than death itself.

They do manage to do something unusual in the Flux - I don't recall if it was about speed though - and come to the attention of some scientists who want to investigate what they've done.  (Maybe this is when the Narsil Rigging Institute is introduced in the series.)

I don't remember anything about seeds, but it's been a long time and my memory isn't clear.

[image: 1978 cover of Star Rigger's Way]